# Between Logic and Group Theory

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, logic, soft-question

I came across a book by William W. Boone titled "Between Logic and Group Theory". I found it quite interesting to work on this as an essay but the book is not available anywhere. Has someone read it? Can you comment anything on the relationship of groups with logic? Will algebra courses suffice for a dissertation on this or will I need to take certain logic courses too?
Is it related to geometric group theory? Are there some interesting problems in logic and group theory that can be explored with the knowledge of Non-commutative rings, Lie Algebras, Category theory, Homological Algebra, Infinite Groups and Algebraic Geometry?

Comment: This is a paper in the 1973 conference proceedings https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0065154 "Proceedings of the Second International Conference on The Theory of Groups Australian National University, August 13–24, 1973"

Comment: Yes, there are several interesting problems in logic and group theory - see for example this [MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261867/applications-of-logic-to-group-theory).